# scoped_session.close() in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am using the `scoped_session` for my APIs from sqlalchemy python

```
class DATABASE():

    def __init__(self):
        engine = create_engine(
                'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % (
                    urllib.parse.quote_plus(
                        'DRIVER={/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so};SERVER=localhost;'
                        'DATABASE=db1;UID=sa;PWD=admin;port=1433;'
                        )), isolation_level='READ COMMITTED', connect_args={'options': '-c lock_timeout=30 -c statement_timeout=30', 'timeout': 40}, max_overflow=10, pool_size=30, pool_timeout=60)

        session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.Session = scoped_session(session)

    def calculate(self, book_id):
        session = self.Session
        output = None
        try:
            result = session.query(Book).get(book_id)
            if result:
                output = result.pages
        except:
            session.rollback()
        finally:
            session.close()
            return output

    def generate(self):
        session = self.Session
        
        try:
            result = session.query(Order).filter(Order.product_name=='book').first()
            pages = self.calculate(result.product_id)
            if not output:
                result.product_details = str(pages)
                session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
        finally:
            session.close()
            return output

database = DATABASE()
database.generate()
```

Here, the session is not committing, then I go through the code, the `generate` function calls the `calculate` function, there, after the calculations are completed, the `session` is closed - due to this, the changes made in the `generate` function is not committed to the database

If I remove the `session.close()` from `calculate` function, the changes made in `generate` function is committed to the database

From the blogs, it is recommend to close the session after API complete its accessing to the database

How to resolve this, and what is the flow of sqlalchemy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scoped sessions default to being *thread-local*, so as long as you are in the same thread, the factory (`self.Session` in this case) will always return the same session.  So `calculate` and `generate` are both using the same session, and closing it in `calculate` will roll back the changes made in `generate`.

Moreover, scoped sessions should not be closed, they should be *removed* from the session registry (by calling `self.Session.remove()`); they will be closed automatically in this case.

You should work out where in your code you will have finished with your session, and remove it there and nowhere else. It will probably be best to commit or rollback in the same place. In the code in the question I'd remove `rollback` and `close` from `calculate`.

The docs on [When do I construct a Session, when do I commit it, and when do I close it?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it) and [Contextual/Thread-local Sessions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions) should be helpful.

Comment: thanks for writing, I need to clarify the flow, so I added new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408591/sqlalchemy-flow-for-contacting-database

could you please take a look on this, thanks

Comment: removing the close() in `calculate` solves the issue, but what happens when the request call is made for `calculate`, at that time, how to close the session?

Comment: This is discussed in the first link in my answer: you need to separate session management from your business logic, for example, start a session, call your API function, then commit/rollback. Don;t commit/rollback inside the API function.